# Align two unordered lists side by side starting at the top

Tags: html, css

I have two uls aligned next to each other in separate divs:

`div{
    display:inline-block;
    width:320px;
}`

```
<div>
    <ul>
    <li>line 1</li>
    <li>line 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>

  <div>
    <ul>
    <li>line 1</li>
    <li>line 2</li>
    <li>line 3</li>
    <li>line 4</li>
    <li>line 5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

This looks fine when the two are next to each other and have the same number of elements, but the div with the smallest number of items is pushed to the bottom and looks very misaligned. I'm not sure how to make sure the top div or its ul are aligned at the top so that the child elements, etc. do not appear at the bottom.

edit: jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/v0bzkhqq/

It looks like using  vertical-align: text-top;  will work.. so I feel slow now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added "vertical-align: top"  to the divs and that will do it.

Answer (score 4):

You can `float: left` the unordered lists and still set the width for them.

```
div {
    float: left;
    width: 320px;
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v0bzkhqq/)

UPDATE:

You can also add a `vertical-align: top;` if you want to keep `display: inline-block;`

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 320px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/hawzz74k/)